# Trying to get property of non-object & Undefined Index errors PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to have posts from a user show on their profile, the current query I'm using worked fine for showing posts by everyone but when I try to edit it to only show posts by the users profile I am on it outputs these errors:

Notice: Undefined index: Tezma in C:\xampppp\htdocs\socialnetwork\profile_page.php on line 62

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampppp\htdocs\socialnetwork\profile_page.php on line 70

This is all the code that I have so far:

```
<?php
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login");
        if($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $username = $_GET[$data->username]; <-- Line 62

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM posts
                WHERE post_user_name = $username
                ORDER BY post_date DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {  <-- Line 70
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<div class='well well-sm'>";
                echo "<img style='float:left;margin-right:6px;box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #888;' src='user_pictures/default.jpg' width='7%'>";
                echo "<span class='bold'><a href='profile.php?user=".$row['post_user_name']."'>".$row['post_user_name']."</a></span><br>";
                echo "<span>".$row['post_date']."</span>";
                echo "<hr style='margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;'>";
                echo "<p style='margin-bottom:0px;'>".$row['post_content']."</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class='well well-sm'>";
            echo "0 Results";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the line 62?i can't see Tezma in your code

Comment: Line 62 is "$username = $_GET[$data->username];"

Comment: Line 70 is "if($result->num_rows > 0) {"

Comment: $result is false.it is second error

Comment: Those are notices, not errors, and seem to be in the file profile_page.php not in the code you posted. Correct it and that's it

Comment: fix the undefined error and the rest should follow.

Comment: show the url how did you view this file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Borgtex. If they aren't errors shouldn't my query still be showing results then?

Comment: the URL is: socialnetwork/profile.php?user=Tezma but on my profile.php page I include_once profile_page.php which is where majority of my code it including the code shown above.

Comment: Line 62: $data->username appears to contain "Tezma"  as a $_GET-key, but that element ( $_GET['Tezma'] ) doesnt exist (probably you need to use $_GET['user'], not $_GET[$data->username]).

Comment: @TheTezma basically `$_GET['Tezma'];` is the problem your url has no parameter as Tezma

Comment: @TheTezma then it should be `$_GET['user'];` not `$_GET['Tezma'];` what is $data? so your query fail and return false then you get second error

Comment: Line 70 is an if-statement. It evaluates $result->num_rows, but num_rows is not a property of $result...

Comment: Still stuck on the line 70 issue

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure with line 62

```
$username = $_GET[$data->username];
```

$_GET[KEY] is retrieving value from key in the URL. Does the URL look like :`username=username`

Comment: Yep, it should be $_GET['user'], as commented above already :-)

Comment: the URL is: socialnetwork/profile.php?user=Tezma but on my profile.php page I include_once profile_page.php which is where majority of my code it including the code shown above, I am trying to retrieve posts created by the user from my database.

Comment: try and add add $result->store_result(); before line 70 seen here:http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.num-rows.php